# Does GHC generate optimized code for `mapM_`?

Tags: haskell, io

I wrote this code,

```
import System.FilePath ((</>))

fp = "/Users/USER/Documents/Test/"

fpAcc = fp </> "acc.txt"

paths = map (fp </>) ["A.txt", "B.txt", "C.txt"]

main :: IO ()
main =
    writeFile fpAcc ""
        >> return paths
        >>= mapM_ ((appendFile fpAcc =<<) . readFile)
        >> readFile fpAcc >>= putStrLn
```

and this is the definition of `mapM_`:

```
mapM_ :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m ()
mapM_ f = foldr c (return ())
-- See Note [List fusion and continuations in 'c']
where c x k = f x >> k
    {-# INLINE c #-}
```

Is the expression `mapM_ ((appendFile fpAcc =<<) . readFile)` producing 3 write operations to the disk, or due to some kind of GHC optimization, only one?

Would be great if the compiler could generate code that uses an intermediate memory to hold the appended data and then write only once. But, since `mapM_` maps each element of the structure to a monadic action, perhaps each step performs one write operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not optimized. The code you wrote will open `fpAcc`, write some bytes, and close `fpAcc` once for each element in paths. Indeed, it would be incorrect for the compiler to optimize this: opening and closing a file is observable from outside the program, so an optimization that opened the file just once would be a behavioral change, not just a speed change.